# mysql: need help to optimize my query/table

Tags: mysql, index, optimization

I'm wondering if someone could help me optimize my tables/query to speed up a query. It is currently running ridiculously slow. I think a well-thought out index could help me. Any help would be really appreciated

Tables URLS and TAGS mentioned below are 2 and 20 million rows respectively (will probably end up having 10x). A query like the one below already takes 10 seconds to run.

An Example:
**http://whatrethebest.com/php+tutorials**

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAGS` (
`hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `my_unique_key` (`hash`,`tag`),
KEY `tag` (`tag`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `URLS` (
`url` text NOT NULL,
`domain` text,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`numsaves` int(11) NOT NULL,
`firstsaved` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`md5`),
UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
KEY `numsaves` (`numsaves`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT urls.md5, urls.url, urls.title, urls.numsaves
FROM urls
JOIN tags ON urls.md5 = tags.hash
WHERE tags.tag
IN (
'php', 'tutorials'
)
GROUP BY urls.md5
HAVING COUNT( * ) =2
ORDER BY urls.numsaves DESC
LIMIT 20
```

**EXPLAIN**

I'm not sure what this shows

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  tags    range   my_unique_key,tag   tag     767     NULL    230946  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  urls    eq_ref  PRIMARY,md5     PRIMARY     767     jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.tags.hash    1
```

So I think the problem is:

certain tags like 'php have 34,000 entries, most of which only have under 5 saves. But in order to get the 20 most saved it is having to sort them all.Right?

I can't really create a 'numsaves' column in TAGS and index on that because that number will be changing up and down, and that wouldnt make sense. Is it possible to create a cross-table index between urls.numsaves and tags.tag? Or a third table to use in my query somehow? Would this solve my problem? I know almost nothing about indexing.

Any help would be really appreciated!

---

***EDITS BELOW***

**RESPONSE TO YperCube:**

Thank you, Thank you, your suggestions have sped up my queries by a factor of 10-20X .
This is an immense improvement. I can't thank you enough.

I'm posting my current queries and tables with execution times in case you or anyone else has any more optimization suggestions. I am worried that as my table grows I may not be able to keep my search times under 3 seconds, which would be a killer.

**New Query Example 1**

```
SELECT u.id, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
FROM urls AS u
JOIN tags AS t1 ON t1.url_id = u.id
AND t1.tag = 'programming'
JOIN tags AS t2 ON t2.url_id = u.id
AND t2.tag = 'language'
ORDER BY u.numsaves DESC
LIMIT 20 

Showing rows 20 - 19 ( 20 total, Query took 0.2009 sec) 

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t2  ref     tag_id  tag_id  767     const   53820   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t1  ref     tag_id  tag_id  772     const,jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t2.url_id  1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_numsaves_IX  PRIMARY     4   jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t2.url_id    1
```

**Neq Query Example 2** (seems to be slower)

```
SELECT u.id, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
FROM urls AS u
JOIN 
( SELECT ui.id, ui.numsaves
FROM urls AS ui
JOIN tags AS t1 ON  t1.url_id = ui.id
AND t1.tag = 'programming'
JOIN tags AS t2 ON  t2.url_id = ui.id
AND t2.tag = 'language'
ORDER BY ui.numsaves DESC
LIMIT 20
) AS ulim ON ulim.id = u.id
ORDER BY ulim.numsaves DESC ;

Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 2,794,577 total, Query took 0.4633 sec)

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    20  Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     u   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_numsaves_IX  PRIMARY     4   ulim.id     1   
2   DERIVED     t2  ref     tag_id  tag_id  767         53820   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     t1  ref     tag_id  tag_id  772     jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t2.url_id    1   Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED     ui  eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_numsaves_IX  PRIMARY     4   jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t2.url_id    1
```

**Using Query Example on a Single Tag** (slower by a lot)

```
SELECT u.id, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
FROM urls AS u
JOIN tags AS t1 ON t1.url_id = u.id
AND t1.tag = 'programming'
ORDER BY u.numsaves DESC
LIMIT 20 

Showing rows 20 - 19 ( 20 total, Query took 3.7395 sec)

id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t1  ref     tag_id  tag_id  767     const   200576  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY,id_numsaves_IX  PRIMARY     4   jcooper_whatrethebest_urls.t1.url_id    1
```

I'm not sure why this one is so much slower?

Do you have any ideas of a query to optimize for querying a single tag?

**My Current Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE `urls` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`url` text NOT NULL,
`domain` text,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`description` text,
`numsaves` int(11) NOT NULL,
`firstsaved` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`md5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `md5` (`md5`),
KEY `id_numsaves_IX` (`id`,`numsaves`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2958560 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
`url_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `tag_id` (`tag`,`url_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thank you again

Comment: Please don't cross post. It would be good if you deleted the identical question at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092811/need-help-to-speed-up-or-optimize-my-query

Answer (score 1):

Add an index on `(tag, hash)`

```
ALTER TABLE tags
  DROP INDEX tag,
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX tag_hash_UX
    (tag, `hash`) ;
```

Then try this query:

```
SELECT u.md5, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
FROM urls AS u
  JOIN tags AS t1 ON  t1.hash = u.md5
                  AND t1.tag = 'php'
  JOIN tags AS t2 ON  t2.hash = u.md5
                  AND t2.tag = 'tutorials'
ORDER BY u.numsaves DESC
  LIMIT 20 ;
```

and after adding another index:

```
ALTER TABLE urls
  DROP INDEX md5,
  ADD INDEX md5_numsaves_IX
    (md5, numsaves) ;
```

try this variation (explanation below, at point 3):

```
SELECT u.md5, u.url, u.title, u.numsaves
FROM urls AS u
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT ui.md5, ui.numsaves
      FROM urls AS ui
        JOIN tags AS t1 ON  t1.hash = ui.md5
                  AND t1.tag = 'php'
        JOIN tags AS t2 ON  t2.hash = ui.md5
                  AND t2.tag = 'tutorials'
      ORDER BY ui.numsaves DESC
        LIMIT 20
    ) AS ulim ON ulim.md5 = u.md5
ORDER BY ulim.numsaves DESC ;
```

---

Other things you should consider:

- You have 2 identical indexes on `URLS (md5)`, one Primary and one Unique. You don't need both, you can safely delete the redundant (unique) index.
- Why was `md5` was chosen as the primary key in the first place? Why not a surrogate (auto-incrementing) integer column? That is usually a better choice for primary key in InnODB tables because the primary key is also by default the clustered index of the table.

  If you make that change (add an `url_id` column and make it PK), you will also need to alter the `TAGS` table by adding a `url_id` as well and removing the `hash` column. This would help efficiency, too. Indexes on `int` columns take much less space than indexes on `VARCHAR(255)` columns. 4 bytes vs. 757 bytes wide is a lot of difference.
- Read this blog post about text and blob columns in InnoDB: [Handling long texts/blobs in InnoDB](http://yoshinorimatsunobu.blogspot.gr/2010/11/handling-long-textsblobs-in-innodb-1-to.html) If the issue turns out to be the text columns, you could split the table into two tables, having an 1-1 relationship between them, so text columns are separately from the narrow columns (or try the index I suggested, which is a similar fix for this.)

Comment: This isn't currently much faster but I think it is because the index is still running! http://whatrethebest.com/test.php

Comment: If it ends up working THANK YOU THANK YOU!!~

Comment: @JamesCooper Yeah, it will take some time to create an index on 20M rows table.

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAINs after the index was added?

Comment: It's still going very slow I *think* the index finished although I'm not sure how to tell. I'm editing my answer to put in the explain

Comment: It should have finished. You can see with `SHOW CREATE TABLE tags ;`

Comment: It seems to have worked! Thank you! I have posted edits to my question in case you have any more suggestions

Comment: I will definitely accept this answer in a day or so, I just want to see if any other people stumble across it first.

Comment: Nice answer, especially under the heading `Other things you should consider:`. +1 on this.